# how to set icon for Toolbar Item in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My xamarin andorid project does not have `Drawawble` folders under `Resources`, I have `mipmap` folders instead. I'm trying to set icon for a toolbar item in shared project. If I set an image as embeded resource I should be able to access it from the shared project, am I wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="BoringAppUi.MainPage" Title="Main Page">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Clicked="OnLogoutButtonClicked" Order="Primary"  Priority="0"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Home" Icon="@mipmap/baseline_home_blue_48.png" Clicked="OnHomeIconClicked" Order="Primary" Priority="1"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Main app content goes here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Also I've tried setting it from the code behind

```
var toolbarItemHome = new ToolbarItem
{
    Text = "Home",
    Icon = "@mipmap/baseline_home_blue_48.png"
};
toolbarItemHome.Clicked += OnHomeIconClicked;
ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItemHome);
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From c# code:

```
new ToolbarItem () { Icon = "icon.png"}
```

Or from xaml:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="iconexample" Icon="icon.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="Onclick" />
```

Have that in mind:

`iOS` - place the image at `/mipmap/icon.png`

`Android` - place the image at `/mipmap/drawable/icon.png`

Comment: I don't have `drawable` folders under `Resources`, VS 2017 xamarin android project creation tool only created `mipmap` folders

Comment: As per my knowledge, you should only put App Icons inside the MipMap because MipMap will automatically adjust the resolution based upon the device' current density. 
So, Other than Launcher Icons or other app icons you should put them in Drawable. If you dont have those folders, you can create one.

Comment: I was reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-resource-basics?tabs=vswin) documentation on microsoft's, if you check the second comment `...this topic has become outdated because the names of the default resources have changed since it was written....`

Comment: I'd like to point out that you have to set the photo's Build Action to `AndroidResource` in order for this to work in Android

Comment: It dont seem to work form code behind